# LINQ groupby when two attributes are the same

Tags: c#, linq

So i have two objects that i join together but on some occasions lines from object `x` will have two properties that will be the duplicates on another object so for simplicity we can call them `PropertyOne` and `PropertyTwo` and when those two are the same i want to group them together into one line and take the sum of the amount field the two objects have

i have this linq where without the `groupby` part it works to get all lines but it then have the objects where the properties are the same as their own "lines" and not the same. How would i change this to make it group them properly

```
 transactions = (from x in data.Transactions
                            join y in data.OtherTransactions
                            on x.TransId equals y.TransId
                            group x by x.PropertyOne, x.PropertyTwo
                       select new OtherFinancialTransactionsItems
                       {
                           Description = x.Description,
                           LineAmount = y.Amount
                       }).ToList();
```

Sample data

```
data.Transactions = [
{Transaction: TransId: 1, Description: "Foo", PropertyOne: "123", PropertyTwo: "100"},
{Transaction: TransId: 2, Description: "Blah", PropertyOne: "456", PropertyTwo: "200"},
{Transaction: TransId: 3, Description: "Foo", PropertyOne: "123", PropertyTwo: "100"}
]

data.OtherTransactions = [
{OtherTransactions: TransId: 1, Amount: 5000},
{OtherTransactions: TransId: 2, Amount: 7500},
{OtherTransactions: TransId: 3, Amount: 5000}
]
```

And the expected outcome would be two lines

```
OtherFinancialTransactionsItems [
{OtherFinancialTransactionsItem: Description: "Foo", Amount: 10000},
{OtherFinancialTransactionsItem: Description: "Blah", Amount: 7500},
]
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data and expected outcome.

Comment: @mm8 added some examples on how it should work

Comment: Based on your expected outcome, it seems like you want to be grouping on `x.Description`, not `x.PropertyOne, x.PropertyTwo`. Otherwise it doesn't make sense as your group (by `x.PropertyOne, x.PropertyTwo`) could be comprised of elements with different `Description` values.

Comment: @Flater mm8 answer is correct for this with the only piece i needed to add where description also in grouping because it ended up being that i needed all three of those properties to be the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work if I understand your requirements correctly:

```
transactions = (from x in data.Transactions
                join y in data.OtherTransactions
                on x.TransId equals y.TransId
                let temp = new
                {
                    x.Description,
                    y.Amount,
                    x.PropertyOne,
                    x.PropertyTwo
                }
                group temp by new { x.PropertyOne, x.PropertyTwo } into g
                select new OtherFinancialTransactionsItems
                {
                    Description = g.First().Description,
                    LineAmount = g.Sum(x => x.Amount)
                }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to group only records which have these properties equal. And concatenate with records with not equal.

```cs
var joined =
    from x in data.Transactions
    join y in data.OtherTransactions on x.TransId equals y.TransId
    select new { x, y };

var withEqual = 
    from q in joined
    where q.x.PropertyOne == q.x.PropertyTwo 
    group q by new { q.x.PropertyOne, x.Description } into g
    select new 
    {
        g.Key.Description,
        LineAmount = g.Sum(m => m.y.Amount)
    }

var notEqual = 
    from q in joined
    where q.x.PropertyOne != q.x.PropertyTwo 
    select new 
    {
        q.x.Description,
        LineAmount = q.y.Amount
    }   

var transactions = withEqual
    .Concat(notEqual)
    .Select(x => new OtherFinancialTransactionsItems
    {
        Description = x.Description,
        LineAmount = y.Amount
    })
    .ToList();
```

This query is close to your requirement, but I think you have missed something.